# Image separators in a WordPress menu

Tags: css, wordpress

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: snapshot image separators wp menu]

What I tried:

```
.nav li a:before {
content: url(../../images/separator.png);
line-height:87px;
}
.nav li:first-child a:before {content:'';}
```

But now of course the separator is part of the link, and only the first menu item is vertically centered with the image.The rest of the menu items are in line with the bottom of the image.

I also tried using the separator image as background to list items, but couldn't get it to look right.

Comment: Can you post a working demo on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: And how is this menu being generated at template level?

Comment: I have a feeling a background image might be the most feasible way to go here. It might be difficult though if each item must be able to overlap with the `/` (like the `T` in Palvelut that occupies part of the `/`'s space)